# How do I use the Lightroom print template for calendars?

Tags: lightroom

I want to create a 2016 calendar and found http://lightroomkillertips.com/lightroom-2015-calendar-template-presets/ (also mentioned on Adobe forum).  I followed it and downloaded http://www.redphotographic.com/lr-calendar-templates/Revised%202016%20Calendars%20Starting%20Sunday.zip from http://www.redphotographic.com/lr-calendar-templates/.  The instructions say:

> After you get them installed, you import the JPEG months and drag and
>   drop them into the cell on the bottom of the page; then drag and drop
>   the shots you want from your images at the top of the page, and you’re
>   good as gold (though Ed has a full, more detailed instruction manual
>   on this download page).

But this isn't working (Lightroom CC 2015 release).

Here is what I'm doing:

- Imported the templates and they reside user User Templates
- Selected the photos of Calendar months and Photos to go with the months
- Changed to the Print module
- Chose "Calendar 17 X 22 Portrait 1 Month" template.  It says "Page 1 of 1"
- I dragged the 12 months to one of the spots and the first month is shown.  But it still says "Page 1 of 1".

Can anyone advise how the templates are meant to be used?  It is like I need to create copies of the template.

I also posted this to https://forums.adobe.com/message/8262548#8262548 but asking here also as a hope to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

### I received this answer at the Adobe forums site.

Hi oehmsmith,

Please refer the below links.

Make a 2015-2016 Calendar in Lightroom - YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6Pd27WJy7U)

How to Create a 2015 Calendar in the Lightroom Print Module (http://digital-photography-school.com/create-2015-calendar-lightroom-print-module/)

Hope that helps.
Regards,
~Mohit

---

I answered:

Excellent thanks Mohit.

I was reading too much into it.  I made a Blurb book a year ago and to do it I just dragged the pictures to the template and all photo fields were filled out.  Shazam!  Where with the Calendars each month has to be prepared independently.

Cheers,

Brooke